# How to use DynamoDB streams to maintain duplicated data consistency?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

From what I understand one of the uses cases of DynamoDB Streams is to maintain/update duplicated data.

Let's say I have a `User` object, and its `name` attribute is replicated in many `Invoice` objects.

When a `User` edits/updates its name, I will have a lambda using DynamoDb Streams to then update all `Invoices` related to this user with his new name.

There could be thousands of `Invoices` related to this user so this updating could take a while, specially because I will want to do a rate limited batch_write so that this operation doesn't throttle my table.

**The question is** : How can my (web)application know that the lambda has finished updating? For example, I want to show a loading screen to the client using the application untill the duplicated data updating is done, so that he doesn't see any outdated information on his browser.

Or is there other ways of rapidly dealing with updating thousands of duplicated data?

Comment: why not segregate the fields which are frequently changing and then do an application level join. Because even if you try to see if the data is latest or not, you will end up creating another table keeping a track of in progress.

Comment: @bestwishes I'm not sure I can visualize what you're trying to say here

Comment: basically storing name in different field. and doing join while returning invoice.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you capturing the output of Lambda. You can make Lambda return successful status, once all the updates are persisting to DDB.

Answer (score 0):

Invoice can keep a reference to User object instead of storing the exact name and can fetch name at the time of generating/printing

Comment: Yes but that's just emulating a foreign key